# Tkinter won't run loop in back

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

I have this program that outputs something when you push yes or no, but it doesn't want to start my loop until i close the tkinter window. The goal of the tkinter window is to stop the loop when i press no, the stop button isn't really necessary I just put it there to close the window.

code:
import tkinter as tk

```
choice = False

def ja():
    global choice
    choice == True
    print("1 works")    # To check if this works

def nee():
    global choice
    choice == False
    print("2 works")    # Also to check if works

def prog():
    while True:
        if choice:
            print("3 works")
            # Program here

        if not choice:
            print("4 works")
            # Program here
            
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Bot")
label1 = tk.Label(root, text="continue?", width=75, height=25)
Yes = tk.Button(root, text="Yes", width=25, height=5, command=ja)
No = tk.Button(root, text="No", width=25, height=5, command=nee)
Stop= tk.Button(root, text="Stop", width=25, height=5, command=root.quit)

label1.pack()
Yes.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.LEFT)
No.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.LEFT)
Stop.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.LEFT)

root.mainloop()
prog()
```

Outcome when i pushed yes and no 2 times and then stop (NOTE: when you push stop the loop just playes until the ide crashes. I am aware of this and its kind of needed for my project so this isn't a bug.):

```
1 works
1 works
2 works
2 works
2 works
4 works
4 works
4 works
4 works
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works:

```
import tkinter as tk
global choice
choice=False
def ja():
    global choice
    choice=True
    print("Yes works")    # To check if this works

def nee():
    global choice
    choice=False
    print("No works")    # To check if this works

def prog():
    if choice:
        print("Prog works")
        # Program here
    root.after(20,prog)
            
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Bot")
label1 = tk.Label(root, text="continue?", width=75, height=25)
Yes = tk.Button(root, text="Yes", width=25, height=5, command=ja)
No = tk.Button(root, text="No", width=25, height=5, command=nee)
Stop= tk.Button(root, text="Stop", width=25, height=5, command=lambda: root.destroy())

label1.pack()
Yes.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.LEFT)
No.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.LEFT)
Stop.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.LEFT)
root.after(20, prog)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `after`. The `prog()` function is called after `mainloop()` so once you close the window, the while loop starts.

```
import tkinter as tk
global choice
choice=False
def ja():
    
    choice == True
    print("1 works")    # To check if this works

def nee():
    
    choice == False
    print("2 works")    # Also to check if works

def prog():
    
    if choice:
        print("3 works")
        # Program here
    elif not choice:
        print("4 works")
        # Program here
    root.after(20,prog)
            
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Bot")
label1 = tk.Label(root, text="continue?", width=75, height=25)
Yes = tk.Button(root, text="Yes", width=25, height=5, command=ja)
No = tk.Button(root, text="No", width=25, height=5, command=nee)
Stop= tk.Button(root, text="Stop", width=25, height=5, command=lambda: root.destroy())

label1.pack()
Yes.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.LEFT)
No.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.LEFT)
Stop.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.LEFT)
root.after(20, prog)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: when calling the loop for the first time You might as well just call `prog()` and also this is not how to do it, You should do like this: `root.after(20, prog)`. The thing is that now it execute immediately anyways and it just does not make sense to do it like this. You either use **just** `prog()` or `root.after(20, prog)`

Comment: You should also fix the line `choice == True` and `choice == False` to `choice = True` and `choice = False` and add back `global choice` inside `ja()` and `nee()`.